# After resetting field, I keep getting Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am creating a number guesser game.
When I run my game, the functionality works but when I reset my game by clicking on the reset button I keep getting:

```
script.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at HTMLButtonElement.guessToUI
```

I have scanned the StackOverflow pages with similar questions like mine but I have not been able to find a definitive solution to my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```js
var actualNum = randomNumber();

function randomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
}

function findCorrectGuess(actualNum, userGuess) {
  if (userGuess > actualNum) {
    return "That is too high!"
  } else if (userGuess < actualNum) {
    return "That is too low!"
  } else if (userGuess === actualNum) {
    return "BOOM!"
  }
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById('input').value = "";
  document.getElementById('player-guess').remove();
  listeners();
}

function clearField() {
  document.getElementById('input').value = "";
}

function guessToUI() {
  let userGuess = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('player-guess').innerHTML = `<center><h1>Your last guess was</h1><h2>${userGuess}</h2><h3>${findCorrectGuess(parseInt(actualNum),parseInt(userGuess))}</h3></center>`
}

function listeners() {
  document.getElementById('guesser').addEventListener('click', guessToUI);
  document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', clearField);
  document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);
}

listeners();
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <center><span id="num">Number</span> <span id="guess">Guesser</span></center>
  </h1>
</header>
<div class="center-block">
  <input id="input" type="number" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your guess"><br>
  <button id="guesser" class="btn">Guess</button>
  <button id="clear" class="btn">Clear</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="player-guess">

</div>

<footer class="bottom">
  <button id='reset' class="btn">Reset</button>
</footer>
```

Comment: What browser are you encountering this error on? I'm using Google Chrome and don't encounter any errors.

Comment: Strange, I am using Google Chrome myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing your DOM element on reset:

```
document.getElementById('player-guess').remove();
```

Try this instead

```
document.getElementById('player-guess').innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: That removes the error, but now it doesn't remove the innerHTML that I put on the screen. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user3763875 Should work, but you can also try `while (el.firstChild) el.removeChild(el.firstChild)` with el being `document.getElementById('player-guess')`
Otherwise please update your question with your full new code.